# Is Boris Johnson the only politician in British history to set up a photoshoot of the signing of their own resignation letter?

Tags: politics, united-kingdom, boris-johnson

Tom Watson, deputy leader of the British Labour party, [said this about  outgoing foreign secretary Boris Johnson in an interview on radio station LBC](https://www.lbc.co.uk/radio/presenters/nick-ferrari/tom-watsons-brutal-burn-for-boris-johnson/):

> [Boris Johnson is] the only politician in UK history that posed for a photograph
>   while signing his own resignation letter.

*(the context of the remark is Watson criticising the resignation, characterising it as a vainglorious stunt intended to boost his leadership ambitions - the claim that he's the only British politician in history to do this is used to support the idea that it goes beyond typical political antics)*

There seems to be no doubt that Boris Johnson did take time out of his schedule (seemingly, [at a time when he was expected to be hosting a summit of East European ministers](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/politics/boris-johnson-resigns-western-balkan-summit-no-show-london-brexit-theresa-may-david-davis-a8438946.html)) to organise a photoshoot and pose for photographs signing his own resignation letter. Tabloid The Sun ([edited by a jogging partner of Boris Johnson](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2017/oct/02/picture-boris-johnson-tony-gallagher-running), therefore likely to be an informed and sympathetic source) credits the photos to professional photographer Andrew Parsons, [and includes multiple poses from different angles in a gallery, describing the photoshoot](https://www.thesun.co.uk/news/6738979/boris-johnson-resigns-theresa-may-brexit/):

> Boris - who's been replaced by Jeremy Hunt - hired photographer Andrew
>   Parsons, who used to work for David Cameron, to capture the moment he
>   formally resigned.

Is it true that this is the first time a British politician has arranged for a photographer to photograph the signing of their own resignation?

Comment: Seems plausible. A Google search for images of "resignation signing" turned up lots of photo-library images of resignation letters, some non-UK politicians (generally resigning in public disgrace) and pictures of Boris Johnson from the current news.

Comment: I am having difficulty to see why this is a notable claim. Is there anybody who believes that hiring a photographer for a resignation photo shoot is a normal thing to do? What is the reason we should be skeptical about this?

Comment: "Only time ever" is a bold claim, and I'd like to know if it's true or not. No-one's doubting it's an unusual, remarkable thing to do (especially since he apparently [stood up a major summit of foreign ministers organised months in advance in order to do it](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/politics/boris-johnson-resigns-western-balkan-summit-no-show-london-brexit-theresa-may-david-davis-a8438946.html)...), but there's a big difference between "X is unusual" and "this is first time X has ever happened"

Comment: @Jordy believe it or not, this site isn't *only* for debunking outrageous conspiracy theories...! It can also be used in cases where a claim looks reasonable, but was presented without supporting evidence, and you want to check if it really is true

Comment: I very much suspect it is true; note it is somewhat a "disprove a negative" question as the claim is that none of the others did.

Comment: @user568458, according to the [FAQ](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/39853): *"[A good question contains] a brief explanation of why it is important."* Nobody's world will stop spinning if the claim is true (or not). I agree that the source is notable, but I can't believe that makes every utterance a notable claim a priori. However you seem to believe this claim should be getting some attention from this community, so to rephrase my original question: why is it important for you/what would change for you if it turns out to be false?

Comment: @Jordy *sigh* yes, I know, that's why I explained the context already, in the section in italics. If the claim is true, it's a remarkable detail about one of the biggest recent stories in British politics, worth repeating. If the claim is not true, then those occasion(s) when it happened in the past would give some interesting perspective or parallels to said story. But it's enough that it's an unreferenced factual claim made in public by a notable figure (a deputy opposition leader).

Comment: @user568458, "it's a remarkable detail", here is where I disagree (and why I referenced the FAQ). It is remarkable that he did it in the first place (which should be proof enough that it "goes beyond *typical* political antics") , the fact that he was the first to do it adds nothing to that affect. Continued..

Comment: "But it's enough that it's an unreferenced factual claim made in public by a notable figure", this is also not true, this [meta answer](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3785/39853) shows that an utterance by a notable person isn't automatically a notable claim. Albeit that in that question the reversal was true, where nobody believes it is true, here there is no reason to assume it is false. If we are still in disagreement I suggest we create a meta-post.

Comment: I got very confused and thought he'd resigned as Prime Minister without me hearing about it, before clicking through and realising this question was from last year...